# PHP What is the best approach for a profile with sub pages?

Tags: php

I see multiple websites using a similar URL approach that I'm after. It looks something like this.

https://example.com/users/84jdn59nmandbn4/profile
or
https://example.com/users/84jdn59nmandbn4/achievements

The random blob is the user's unique ID string. How is this achievable in PHP without the creation of a folder with the random string name?

Comment: Through PHP, it's not.  You could possibly use an .htaccess redirect to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The original url is something like this

```
https://example.com/users.php?id=84jdn59nmandbn4&profile

https://example.com/users.php?id=84jdn59nmandbn4&achievements
```

Using Apache's rewrite engine you can create search-engine-friendly (SEF) urls

example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?PID=$1&ID=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?PID=$1 [L,QSA]
```

source: [mod_rewrite: Trailing slash on URL with two GET variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299208/mod-rewrite-trailing-slash-on-url-with-two-get-variables)